# Solving birthday problem without complement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

I'm trying to find the probability of at least 2 people in a room of 4 sharing the same birthday (without using complements).

I began by breaking the problem down into 4 cases:

Let E = the event that at least 2 people share the same birthday in a room of 4.

Our sample size: $365^4$

Case 1: 4 people share the same birthday: 365 ways

Case 2: 3 people share the same birthday, 1 distinct birthday: $365 \cdot 364 \cdot C(4,3)$

Case 3: 2 people share a birthday, another 2 people share some other birthday: $365 \cdot 364 \cdot \frac{C(4,2)}{2}$

Case 4: 2 people share same birthday, 2 distinct birthdays: $365 \cdot 364 \cdot 363 \cdot C(4,2) \cdot 2$

After adding up all the cases and dividing by the sample size to find probability the answer had an over-count. I checked my answer by doing $$P(E) = 1- \frac{365 \cdot 364 \cdot 363 \cdot 362}{365^4}$$

Where did I have an over-count? Thank you!

---

Here is an example that works with n = 3 people and at least 2 people share same birthday.

Case 1: 3 people share same birthday: 365

Case 2: 2 Same birthdays, 1 different: $365 \cdot 364 \cdot \binom{3}{2}$

$$P(E) = \frac{365 + (365 \cdot 364 \cdot \binom{3}{2})}{365^3} \equiv 1 - \frac{365 \cdot 364 \cdot 363}{365^3}$$

Those are both equivalent answers because in the complement we're subtracting away the event that all birthdays are distinct.

Comment: I'd advise you to be more explicit in how you divided/added up to fix overcount.

Comment: Case three.  The four people are named., say Alfred, Bobby, Carlos and Dan.  Pick alfred's birthday.  Pick who else shares alfred's birthday.  Pick the birthday of the remaining two people.  There are $365\cdot 364\cdot 3$ outcomes here, not $365\cdot 364\cdot 6$

Comment: For Case 3, I think you're overcounting. You are counting the pairs of birthdays twice, just naming them in a different order....

Comment: Why is there a $\cdot 2$ at the end of Case 4?

Comment: @user1813840 But [YYXX] *is* the same as [XXYY], for a different choice of X and Y.  Shouldn't there be a factor for 1/2 somewhere to account for this symmetry?

Comment: Thank you guys, got the right answer by removing the 2 in case 4 like Erick suggested and changing the 6 to a 3 like JMoravitz suggested.

Comment: @ErickWong The reason I added $\cdot 2$ is because [XYZZ] and [YXZZ]? aren't they different? However you are right about not needing it, but why not?

Comment: @user1813840 Imagine you are writing down every combination exactly once by filling out various templates like [XYZZ].  You are saying that you need to count both of the templates [XYZZ] and [YXZZ].  But any list of dates that fits the first template (say, [Easter, Christmas, New Year, New Year]) **also** fits the second.  That's double counting!

Comment: @ErickWong The reason I'm still confused is because the way I understood it is, [XYZZ] is X is setting some date for person 1, Y for person 2, ..., Z for person 4. So having switched [XYZZ] to [YXZZ] this is now a different possibility of assigning the dates? Because if we look at the case 2 example, we count [YXXX] as different from [XXXY]

Comment: @user181340 You understand that my Easter example fits both [XYZZ] and [YXZZ] right?  Now try coming up with an example that fits both [YXXX] and [XXXY].  It's impossible.  The difference becomes obvious when you actually *try* with specific dates.

Comment: @ErickWong Finally wrapped my head around it, thank you so much :)

Comment: Probabilites are:
Case 1: 4 people share the same birthday 1/48627125
Case 2: 3 share, one distinct: 1456/48627125
case 3: 2 share and another 2 share: 1092/48627125
Case 4: 2 share 2 distinct: 792792/48627125
Case 5: no shares: 47831784/48627125

Answer (score 2):

When trying out a new way, it is prudent to look to a familiar class of problem, like die tosses in Yahtzee, ( except that here it is a $365$ sided die tossed 4 times.)

We  can then "straightjacket" it into a format  as **[ Choose faces to come up ] $\times$ [ Permute ]**

There are four possibilities:

$4\;of\;a\;kind: [\binom{365}1] \times [\frac {4!}{4!}]$

$3-1\;of\;a\;kind: [\binom{365}1\binom{364}1] \times [\frac{4!}{3!1!}]$

$2-2\;of\;a\;kind: [ \binom{365}2] \times [\frac{4!}{2!2!}]$

$2-1-1\;of\;a\;kind: [\binom{365}1\binom{364}2 \times [\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}]$

Add up to get favorable ways, and divide by $365^4$ to get the final result.

Comment: I didn't see BruceET's comments at that time, but happened to come upon it today. I have counterchecked with the formula using the complement, and found that the two tally **exactly.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 365 equally likely birthdays, here is a simulation of 10 million realizations of the number of unique
birthdays $X$ out of 4. It might help you settle the over-count issue.

```
m = 10^7;  x = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
   room = sample(1:365, 4, repl=T)
   x[i] = length(unique(room))  }
table(x)/m
x
        2         3         4 
0.0000510 0.0163006 0.9836484
```

Notice that event $\{X = 1\}$ did not occur even once
in 10 million 'rooms'. Not really surprising; it's probability is only
`2.056465e-08`. Probabilities for $X = 3$ and $4$ should be
accurate to three places.

**Addendum** (after unexplained down-vote): OP's Case 4 has an incorrect
factor of 2 as Commented by @ErickWong (which prompted, and agrees with, my simulation). This is also @trueblueanil's case `2-1-1`, which again agrees with my simulated $P(X=3) \approx 0.016.$ (+1) [Moreover, sdding cases `3-1` and `2-2` gives less than .0001, as in the simulation for $P(X=2).$]